# Discord.py - how can my discord.bot dm message to someone at certain time? - Solution here

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def timecheck():
    tm = time.localtime()
   
    if tm[6] == 6:
        converter = MemberConverter()
        member = await converter.convert(ctx, 'KexoTV#8921')
        ctx.author = member
        invitelink = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_uses=1, unique=True)
        await ctx.author.send(invitelink)

@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def mainloop():
    asyncio.create_task(timecheck())


mainloop.start()
```

Problem i have is that i don't have ctx defined, i can't put in into def input because the bot will give errors like ctx is not defined

Comment: Do you have a message where you can retrieve a context from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Thörni, it didn't work but it helped me to find the correct commands and that is:

```
user = await client.fetch_user(id)
await user.send(inviteLink)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the ctx object to send messages. Theres multiple other ways, like fetching a [guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild), [channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) or [user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user) by id, and then sending a message to them. All you need is your Client to already be on a server with who you want to dm to. In your case:

```py
user = client.get_user(id) # get_user is synchronous
await user.send(inviteLink)
```

Of course, to do that, you need to save the `id` of who you want to send the message to.